I cannot change name of the App on Flutter
I am a beginner in flutter dev, i have an issue about changing the name of the app on Flutter, the issue is I cannot change the floating name app when i click the "Recent Apps" or "Overview" button to see App that are running in the background,
The name App is always displaying "My App" even though i have change the name App in Android manifest.xml, can anyone help me to find the solution of this problem ?
here is my AndroidManifest.xml :
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:label="Todo App"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility?hl=en and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>


here i put the detail as in the image :


did you hard restart app (re run)  after making changes to android manifest file, hot reload won't work!

i have found the bug, i forgot to change the name in the material widget , now it's fixed

You have to perform some steps to achieve this,
Go to your pubspec.yaml file
and in top you can able to see the project name
Do the changes there and Run the application again

thanks for answering, i have found the bug, i forgot to change the name in the material widget , now it's fixed, thank you
